# Using Html Anchors with MVC3 Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an anchor in one of my views:

```
<a name="@("Doc" + Model.Key)"></a>
```

I want to link to this anchor from another view:

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Update") + "#Doc" + Model.DocumentId)">Go To Document Properties</a>
```

This generates a url like so: `http://localhost:60010/Session/Update#Doc1`

When I click this link, I get the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update(Int32)' in
>   'Controllers.SessionController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I'm using the default route, no custom routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

How can I get MVC to ignore the html anchor in the url (`#Doc1`, for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the advice @BrettSmith posted, I came up with the following solution:

1. I added a second route with the anchor and a constraint, so that this route would only get chosen if the anchor was specified.

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
           "DocAnchor", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}#{anchor}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, anchor = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
           new { anchor = ".+" } // ".+" regex means any character one or more times.
       );

       routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );
   ```
2. I modified my link to this:

   ```
   <a href="@(Url.Action("Update", new { id=Model.DocumentId, anchor="Doc" + Model.DocumentId }).Replace("%23", "#"))">Go To Document Properties</a>
   ```

   Note that I'm passing the anchor as part of the route data object (I also had a bug where I wasn't passing the id, which I fixed as well).  `Url.Action` UrlEncodes the string, so I had to replace the `%23` with the hash char to get the browser to recognize the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

I had a route that did this, but lost it in a hard drive failure, from memory you need to specify a route that includes

```
{controller}/{action}#{documentid}
```

Where documentid could be anything that isn't id

You'll also need to make your controller expect int? id rather than int id